# Back Tracking Search at C# in this Problem

Tags: c#

So i have Works, these have values (jobValue) and the People gets the value if he do the work. Peoples who could do actual work in workersWhoCanDoActualWork.
My task is find all solution with back track search. One people can do more work, but the People's actualValue is max 2000..

Here is the code:

```
    class Work
    {
        public string jobName;
        public int jobValue;

        public List<People> workersWhoCanDoActualWork;

        public Work(string jobName, int jobValue)
        {
            this.jobName = jobName;
            this.jobValue = jobValue;
            workersWhoCanDoActualWork = new List<People>();
        }
    }

    class People
    {
        string peopleName;
        int actualValue;

        public People(string peopleName) 
        {
            this.peopleName = peopleName;
        }

    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<People[]> allResult = new List<People[]>();
            //use BTS to find all solutions
        }
     }
}
```

and i create a basic BTS with anoter problem:

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string[][] r = new string[][] {
                new string[]{"Mike", "Klaudia", "Peter"},
                new string[]{ "Mike", "Andreas"},
                new string[]{ "Andreas", "Samuel"},
                new string[]{"Bob", "Samuel", "Alex"},
                new string[]{ "Bob", "Andreas"},
                new string[]{ "Mike", "Bob"},
            };

            string[] actualResult = new string[r.Length];
            List<string[]> allSoluitons = new List<string[]>();
            BTS(r, 0, actualResult, allSoluitons);
        }

        static void BTS(string[][] r, int level, string[] actualResult, List<string[]> allSoluitons)
        {
            int i = -1;
            while (i < r[level].Length - 1)
            {
                i++;
                if (FK(level, r[level][i], actualResult))
                {
                    actualResult[level] = r[level][i];
                    if (level == r.Length-1)
                    {
                        string[] newResult = new string[actualResult.Length];
                        for (int k = 0; k < newResult.Length; k++)
                        {
                            newResult[k] = actualResult[k];
                        }
                        allSoluitons.Add(newResult);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        BTS(r, level + 1, actualResult, allSoluitons);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        static bool FK(int level, string Name, string[] actualResult)
        {
            bool ok = true;
            for (int i = 0; i < level; i++)
            {
                if (actualResult[i] == Name)
                {
                    ok = false;
                }
            }
            return ok;
        }
    }
```

Comment: So what's the actual question?  What problem are you experiencing with the code you have written?

Answer (score 0):

find all possible solutions if one pople can do more work, but he's actualValue property is max 2000;
List<People[]> allSolutions = new List<People[]>(); --> one People[] array length is equal works.Length... People[] actualResult = new People[works.Length] -->  If people[x] can work works[y] --> People[z] = people[x];  Sorry my English not to good, i hope you can understand :(

```
class Work
        {
            public string jobName;
            public int jobValue;
    
            public List<People> workersWhoCanDoActualWork;
    
            public Work(string jobName, int jobValue)
            {
                this.jobName = jobName;
                this.jobValue = jobValue;
                workersWhoCanDoActualWork = new List<People>();
            }
        }
    
        class People
        {
            public string peopleName;
            public int actualValue;
    
            public People(string peopleName) 
            {
                this.peopleName = peopleName;
                actualValue = 0;
            }
    
        }
        static class RandomNumber
        {
            public static Random rnd = new Random();
        }
    
        class Program
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                int x = 0;
    
                Work[] works = new Work[20];
    
                while (x < works.Length)
                {
                    Work actualWork = new Work((((char)RandomNumber.rnd.Next('A', 'Z')).ToString())
                        + ((char)RandomNumber.rnd.Next('A', 'Z')).ToString() +
                        ((char)RandomNumber.rnd.Next('A', 'Z')).ToString() +
                        ((char)RandomNumber.rnd.Next('A', 'Z')).ToString(),
                        RandomNumber.rnd.Next(100, 1500)
                        );
    
                    if (!works.Contains(actualWork))
                    {
                        works[x] = actualWork;
                        x++;
                    }
                }
                for (int i = 0; i < works.Length; i++)
                {
                    //With random name and values
                    works[i] = new Work((((char)RandomNumber.rnd.Next('A', 'Z')).ToString())
                        + ((char)RandomNumber.rnd.Next('A', 'Z')).ToString() +
                        ((char)RandomNumber.rnd.Next('A', 'Z')).ToString() +
                        ((char)RandomNumber.rnd.Next('A', 'Z')).ToString(),
                        RandomNumber.rnd.Next(100, 1500)
                        );
                }
    
    
                People[] peoples = new People[100];
                x = 0;
                while (x < peoples.Length)
                {
                    People actualPeople = new People((((char)RandomNumber.rnd.Next('A', 'Z')).ToString())
                       + ((char)RandomNumber.rnd.Next('A', 'Z')).ToString() +
                       ((char)RandomNumber.rnd.Next('A', 'Z')).ToString() +
                       ((char)RandomNumber.rnd.Next('A', 'Z')).ToString());
    
                    if (!peoples.Contains(actualPeople))
                    {
                        peoples[x] = actualPeople;
                        x++;
                    }
                }
    
                for (int i = 0; i < works.Length; i++)
                {
                    int random = RandomNumber.rnd.Next(1, 41);
                    for (int j = 0; j < random; j++)
                    {
                        int randomPeopleIndex = RandomNumber.rnd.Next(0, peoples.Length);
                        if ( ! works[i].workersWhoCanDoActualWork.Contains( peoples[randomPeopleIndex] ))
                        {
                            works[i].workersWhoCanDoActualWork.Add(peoples[randomPeopleIndex]);
                        }
                    }
                }
    
    
            }
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I SOLVED THE PROBLEM!

```
class Work
{
    public string jobName;
    public int jobValue;

    public List<People> workersWhoCanDoActualWork;

    public Work(string jobName, int jobValue)
    {
        this.jobName = jobName;
        this.jobValue = jobValue;
        workersWhoCanDoActualWork = new List<People>();
    }
}

class People
{
    public string peopleName;
    public int capacity;

    public People(string peopleName)
    {
        this.peopleName = peopleName;
        this.capacity = 2000;
    }

}

static class RandomNumber
{
    public static Random rnd = new Random();
}

class Program
{
    static Work[] works = new Work[5];
    static People[] peoples = new People[10];

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        AllFileUpload();



        People[] actualiseredmeny = new People[works.Length];
        List<People[]> osszesEredmeny = new List<People[]>();

        BTS(works, 0, actualiseredmeny, osszesEredmeny);

        

    }

    static void BTS(Work[] works, int szint, People[] actualisEredmeny, List<People[]> osszesEredmeny)
    {
        int i = -1;
        while (i < (works[szint].workersWhoCanDoActualWork.Count() - 1))
        {
            i++;
            if (FK(szint, works[szint].jobValue, actualisEredmeny))
            {
                People reszeredmeny = new People(works[szint].workersWhoCanDoActualWork[i].peopleName);
                reszeredmeny.capacity = works[szint].workersWhoCanDoActualWork[i].capacity;

                actualisEredmeny[szint] = reszeredmeny;
                actualisEredmeny[szint].capacity -= works[szint].jobValue;

                if (szint == works.Length - 1)
                {
                    People[] newResult = new People[actualisEredmeny.Length];
                    for (int k = 0; k < newResult.Length; k++)
                    {
                        newResult[k] = new People(actualisEredmeny[k].peopleName); //actualisEredmeny[k];
                        newResult[k].capacity = actualisEredmeny[k].capacity;
                    }
                    osszesEredmeny.Add(newResult);
                }
                else
                {
                    BTS(works, szint + 1, actualisEredmeny, osszesEredmeny);
                }
            }
        }

    }
    static bool FK(int szint, int thisJobCapacity, People[] actualisEredmeny)
    {
        if (szint != 0 && actualisEredmeny[szint] != null)
        {
            if (actualisEredmeny[szint].capacity >= thisJobCapacity)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;

        //bool ok = true;
        //for (int i = 0; i < szint; i++)
        //{
        //    if (actualisEredmeny[i].capacity < thisJobCapacity)
        //    {
        //        ok = false;
        //    }
        //}
        //return ok;
    }
    static void AllFileUpload()
    {
        int x = 0;
        while (x < works.Length)
        {
            Work actualWork = new Work((((char)RandomNumber.rnd.Next('A', 'Z')).ToString())
                + ((char)RandomNumber.rnd.Next('A', 'Z')).ToString() +
                ((char)RandomNumber.rnd.Next('A', 'Z')).ToString() +
                ((char)RandomNumber.rnd.Next('A', 'Z')).ToString(),
                RandomNumber.rnd.Next(100, 1500)
                );

            if (!works.Contains(actualWork))
            {
                works[x] = actualWork;
                x++;
            }
        }
        x = 0;
        while (x < peoples.Length)
        {
            People actualPeople = new People((((char)RandomNumber.rnd.Next('A', 'Z')).ToString())
               + ((char)RandomNumber.rnd.Next('A', 'Z')).ToString() +
               ((char)RandomNumber.rnd.Next('A', 'Z')).ToString() +
               ((char)RandomNumber.rnd.Next('A', 'Z')).ToString());

            if (!peoples.Contains(actualPeople))
            {
                peoples[x] = actualPeople;
                x++;
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < works.Length; i++)
        {
            int random = RandomNumber.rnd.Next(1, peoples.Length / 3);
            for (int j = 0; j < random; j++)
            {
                int randomPeopleIndex = RandomNumber.rnd.Next(0, peoples.Length);
                if (!works[i].workersWhoCanDoActualWork.Contains(peoples[randomPeopleIndex]))
                {
                    works[i].workersWhoCanDoActualWork.Add(peoples[randomPeopleIndex]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```